# Is there an R function for isolating a set of data from a larger dataset by filtering for one attribute and working independently with the data?

Tags: r, function, filter, dataset, grouping

I am working with a large dataset and trying to isolate certain groups of data points by column 1 values. I want to be able to work independently with each of the groups without knowing how many groups there are or the names of the groups. The image is a sample of the dataset. Is there a function to make an object for each of these unique groups with the filter on that group being unique samples in the clade column?

```
df <- read.csv(file.choose(), header=TRUE)
```

Comment: check out `?group_by` from the package `dplyr`

Comment: or `split()` ...

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: `aggregate()` is a handy base R function that can help here. More efficient than dply functions in some cases.

Comment: Here's a great guide to transforming your data: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html#dplyr-basics

Comment: @BenBolker Thank you all! using `split()` helped!

Comment: If you have  a solution, please write it up as an answer to your own question.